# Editing a question to include linebreaks not possible due to "6 non-space characters minimum"

Tags: support

So [this](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/15827/combat-and-exp-gold-reward-equations) question needs editing; the author didn't realise (I assume) that linebreaks need to be inserted by using a 'double-space'.

But editing the question to simply add the linebreaks and make the question easier to understand fails due to the "6 non-space character minimum" requirement.

Are formatting edits in this manner discouraged, or is this something that should be fixed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, they're not.  Users with rep sufficient to edit without approval can make these kind of changes.  Very small edits cannot be proposed, to keep them from drowning out more significant edits in the edit queue.  Users with sufficient reputation will be able to make these kinds of edits.  There is much more discussion about this at [Meta.StackOverflow](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/suggested-edits).

Comment: Yep. And that's exactly what happened: I came along and fixed it before I even saw this on meta.